# Parameterized junit test of custom validation in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit4, customvalidator

I have this validator in springboot which gives error when an integer is not between 1 and 3 and i am using addConstraintViolation to print a message from properties file

```
public class SizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SizeValidation, Integer> {
    private int maxSize = 500;
    private int minSize = 1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(SizeValidation constraintAnnotation) {
        maxSize = constraintAnnotation.mxSize();
        minSize = constraintAnnotation.minSize();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer givenSize, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (givenSize > maxSize || givenSize<= minPageSize) {
            addConstraintViolation(givenSize, "{Size.wrongSize.message}", context);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void addConstraintViolation(Integer givenSize, String errorMessage, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final HibernateConstraintValidatorContext customContext = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
        customContext.addExpressionVariable("givenSize", givenSize);

        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(errorMessage)
                .addConstraintViolation();
    }
}
```

and in my `validation.properties`

> Size.wrongSize.message=Value of size ${givenSize} should be between 1
> and 3

i wanted to write a Parameterized junit test for it as following but it returns `nullpointerexception` where am i doing wrong please?

> ```
>  java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sizeValidator.addConstraintViolation(SizeValidator.java:33)
> ```

intellij says its at position

> context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(errorMessage)
> .addConstraintViolation();

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraintvalidation.HibernateConstraintValidatorContext;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.experimental.runners.Enclosed;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
    
    import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    
        @RunWith(Enclosed.class)
        public class SizeValidatorTest{
        
            @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
            public static class TestValidEntries {
                private SizeValidator validator = new SizeValidator();
                private Integer val;
        
        
                public TestValidEntries(Integer val) {
                    super();
                    this.val = val;
                }
        
                @Test
                public void test() {
                    assertTrue(isValid(val));
                }
        
                @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index} Valid: {0}")
                public static Collection data() {
                    return Arrays.asList(
                            -1, 501
                    );
                }
        
                public boolean isValid(Integer value) {
                    final HibernateConstraintValidatorContext context = mock(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
                    when(context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class)).thenReturn(context);
                    when(context.addExpressionVariable(eq("nonUnique"), anyString())).thenReturn(context);
                    when(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).thenReturn("template");
                    final ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder builder = mock(ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.class);
                    when(context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("template")).thenReturn(builder);
        
                    when(builder.addPropertyNode(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeBuilderCustomizableContext.class));
        
                    return validator.isValid(value, context);
                }
        
            }
        }
```

Comment: what details do you want exactlly ? its about validating integer value on variable level, and i added the error message

Comment: You claim to get a `NullPointerException`, where is the stacktrace?

Comment: see update post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the configuration of the `context` mock.

Your configuration says:

```
when(context
      .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
          "template"))
.thenReturn(builder);
```

But the string you pass in your code under test  is: `"{Size.wrongSize.message}"`
Because this string do not match the mock returns `null`.

---

A better approach is to always use unspecific matchers like `anyString()` in the *arrange* part of the test method (or in *setup*) an specific matchers (or values) only in conjunction with `Mockito.verify()` in the *assert* part of the test method.

Comment: Could you please provide me the working solution based on my config?